# Changing how audio embed shortcodes are generated in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, audio, shortcode

I have a rather annoying problem: I have a wordpress website that, among other things, serves audio files. Wordpress does a nice job of filtering any media inserts to a post and putting a player in, but this isn't much good for allowing downloads of the file as well. Ideally I'd want to change the code that generates the audio player shortcode and add `<a href="URL">Click here to download mp3.</a>` after the `[/audio]` tag, but my PHP is pretty much non-existent.

My current approach is to use python (which I know well) to write an hourly cron script which plays with the mysql database directly using the python mysql connector. If it runs hourly and looks for posts made in the last hour which contain the string `[/audio]`, pulls out the url for the audio file, and uses it to construct a link to append afterwards. The effect of this is the same, with a maximum time delay of one hour between the post being made and the link being available. When I've finished coding it it should work, but I'm sure it's not the best approach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (add this to your functions.php file)

```
function wp_audio_shortcode_dowload_link( $html, $atts, $audio, $post_id, $library ) {
    $html .='<br><a href="'.$atts['src'].'">Download</a>';
    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode','wp_audio_shortcode_dowload_link',5,10);
```

Comment: He can chose how he want to do-it. Both ideas are viable! If yours is not convenient, he can try mine :)

Comment: This is *nearly* what I'm after, only it replaces the audio player with a download link rather than adding a download link after the player. Do you know how I'd modify it to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, bad callback arguments, Fixed !

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet you have the original code for [audio] shortcode. 
It is located in `wp-includes/media.php` and begins at line 2171. The code in this snippet:

```html
2171            function wp_audio_shortcode( $attr, $content = '' ) {
2172         $post_id = get_post() ? get_the_ID() : 0;
2173 
2174         static $instance = 0;
2175         $instance++;
2176 
2177         /**
2178          * Filter the default audio shortcode output.
2179          *
2180          * If the filtered output isn't empty, it will be used instead of generating the default audio template.
2181          *
2182          * @since 3.6.0
2183          *
2184          * @param string $html     Empty variable to be replaced with shortcode markup.
2185          * @param array  $attr     Attributes of the shortcode. @see wp_audio_shortcode()
2186          * @param string $content  Shortcode content.
2187          * @param int    $instance Unique numeric ID of this audio shortcode instance.
2188          */
2189         $override = apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode_override', '', $attr, $content, $instance );
2190         if ( '' !== $override ) {
2191                 return $override;
2192         }
2193 
2194         $audio = null;
2195 
2196         $default_types = wp_get_audio_extensions();
2197         $defaults_atts = array(
2198                 'src'      => '',
2199                 'loop'     => '',
2200                 'autoplay' => '',
2201                 'preload'  => 'none',
2202                 'class'    => 'wp-audio-shortcode',
2203                 'style'    => 'width: 100%; visibility: hidden;'
2204         );
2205         foreach ( $default_types as $type ) {
2206                 $defaults_atts[$type] = '';
2207         }
2208 
2209         $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults_atts, $attr, 'audio' );
2210 
2211         $primary = false;
2212         if ( ! empty( $atts['src'] ) ) {
2213                 $type = wp_check_filetype( $atts['src'], wp_get_mime_types() );
2214                 if ( ! in_array( strtolower( $type['ext'] ), $default_types ) ) {
2215                         return sprintf( '<a class="wp-embedded-audio" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $atts['src'] ), esc_html( $atts['src'] ) );
2216                 }
2217                 $primary = true;
2218                 array_unshift( $default_types, 'src' );
2219         } else {
2220                 foreach ( $default_types as $ext ) {
2221                         if ( ! empty( $atts[ $ext ] ) ) {
2222                                 $type = wp_check_filetype( $atts[ $ext ], wp_get_mime_types() );
2223                                 if ( strtolower( $type['ext'] ) === $ext ) {
2224                                         $primary = true;
2225                                 }
2226                         }
2227                 }
2228         }
2229 
2230         if ( ! $primary ) {
2231                 $audios = get_attached_media( 'audio', $post_id );
2232                 if ( empty( $audios ) ) {
2233                         return;
2234                 }
2235 
2236                 $audio = reset( $audios );
2237                 $atts['src'] = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio->ID );
2238                 if ( empty( $atts['src'] ) ) {
2239                         return;
2240                 }
2241 
2242                 array_unshift( $default_types, 'src' );
2243         }
2244 
2245         /**
2246          * Filter the media library used for the audio shortcode.
2247          *
2248          * @since 3.6.0
2249          *
2250          * @param string $library Media library used for the audio shortcode.
2251          */
2252         $library = apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode_library', 'mediaelement' );
2253         if ( 'mediaelement' === $library && did_action( 'init' ) ) {
2254                 wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
2255                 wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
2256         }
2257 
2258         /**
2259          * Filter the class attribute for the audio shortcode output container.
2260          *
2261          * @since 3.6.0
2262          *
2263          * @param string $class CSS class or list of space-separated classes.
2264          */
2265         $atts['class'] = apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode_class', $atts['class'] );
2266 
2267         $html_atts = array(
2268                 'class'    => $atts['class'],
2269                 'id'       => sprintf( 'audio-%d-%d', $post_id, $instance ),
2270                 'loop'     => wp_validate_boolean( $atts['loop'] ),
2271                 'autoplay' => wp_validate_boolean( $atts['autoplay'] ),
2272                 'preload'  => $atts['preload'],
2273                 'style'    => $atts['style'],
2274         );
2275 
2276         // These ones should just be omitted altogether if they are blank
2277         foreach ( array( 'loop', 'autoplay', 'preload' ) as $a ) {
2278                 if ( empty( $html_atts[$a] ) ) {
2279                         unset( $html_atts[$a] );
2280                 }
2281         }
2282 
2283         $attr_strings = array();
2284         foreach ( $html_atts as $k => $v ) {
2285                 $attr_strings[] = $k . '="' . esc_attr( $v ) . '"';
2286         }
2287 
2288         $html = '';
2289         if ( 'mediaelement' === $library && 1 === $instance ) {
2290                 $html .= "<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->\n";
2291         }
2292         $html .= sprintf( '<audio %s controls="controls">', join( ' ', $attr_strings ) );
2293 
2294         $fileurl = '';
2295         $source = '<source type="%s" src="%s" />';
2296         foreach ( $default_types as $fallback ) {
2297                 if ( ! empty( $atts[ $fallback ] ) ) {
2298                         if ( empty( $fileurl ) ) {
2299                                 $fileurl = $atts[ $fallback ];
2300                         }
2301                         $type = wp_check_filetype( $atts[ $fallback ], wp_get_mime_types() );
2302                         $url = add_query_arg( '_', $instance, $atts[ $fallback ] );
2303                         $html .= sprintf( $source, $type['type'], esc_url( $url ) );
2304                 }
2305         }
2306 
2307         if ( 'mediaelement' === $library ) {
2308                 $html .= wp_mediaelement_fallback( $fileurl );
2309         }
2310         $html .= '</audio>';
2311 
2312         /**
2313          * Filter the audio shortcode output.
2314          *
2315          * @since 3.6.0
2316          *
2317          * @param string $html    Audio shortcode HTML output.
2318          * @param array  $atts    Array of audio shortcode attributes.
2319          * @param string $audio   Audio file.
2320          * @param int    $post_id Post ID.
2321          * @param string $library Media library used for the audio shortcode.
2322          */
2323         return apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode', $html, $atts, $audio, $post_id, $library );
2324 }
2325 add_shortcode( 'audio', 'wp_audio_shortcode' );
```

The idea is to create your own custom version [audio] shortcode, copying and customizing the original code in the `function.php` file of your active child theme or theme.

You should use first `remove_shortcode( 'audio' );` before registering your custom `[audio]` shortcode.

Comment: No need to override the original [audio] shortcode if you can just hook into its output.